# Requiring ruby gems giving mixed results

Tags: ruby, rubygems, irb, pry, fileutils

Noticed today that running `require fileutils` in pry always returns false.  But, if I do the same thing in irb, it returns true.  Furthermore, when fileutils is set to false, it still works!

First I thought that fileutils is a dependency of pry, and that would explain why it is already required. But it's not. Am I missing something fundamental here?

```
[07:40] ~/Desktop $ gem dependency pry
Gem pry-0.10.2
  bundler (~> 1.0, development)
  coderay (~> 1.1.0)
  method_source (~> 0.8.1)
  slop (~> 3.4)

Gem pry-theme-1.1.3
  bundler (~> 1.0, development)
  coderay (~> 1.1)
  json (~> 1.8)
```

**Example**:

First I use pry to make some folders.  Is fileutils already loaded? Notice that even though fileutils returns false it still works:

```
[07:44] ~/Desktop $ ls
[07:44] ~/Desktop $    ########## (nothing)
[07:44] ~/Desktop $ pry
[1] pry(main)> require 'fileutils'
=> false
[2] pry(main)> FileUtils::mkdir_p 'foo'
=> ["foo"]
[3] pry(main)> Dir.mkdir('bar')
=> 0
[4] pry(main)> Dir["/home/caveman/Desktop/*"]
=> ["/home/caveman/Desktop/foo", "/home/caveman/Desktop/bar"]
```

I remove the folders I just created...

```
[07:48] ~/Desktop $ rm -r *
[07:48] ~/Desktop $ ls
[07:48] ~/Desktop $    ########## (nothing again)
```

Now I try again with irb:

```
[07:49] ~/Desktop $ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'fileutils'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> FileUtils::mkdir_p 'foo2'
=> ["foo2"]
irb(main):003:0> Dir.mkdir 'bar2'
=> 0
irb(main):004:0> Dir["/home/caveman/Desktop/*"]
=> ["/home/caveman/Desktop/bar2", "/home/caveman/Desktop/foo2"]
```

Here's what blows my mind. Even after I set 'fileutils' to false in irb, it still works:

```
irb(main):005:0> require 'fileutils'
=> false
irb(main):006:0> FileUtils::mkdir_p 'foo3'
=> ["foo3"]
irb(main):007:0> Dir["/home/caveman/Desktop/*"]
=> ["/home/caveman/Desktop/foo3", "/home/caveman/Desktop/bar2", "/home/caveman/Desktop/foo2"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, FileUtils isn't a gem, so it will never show up as a gem dependency.

Secondly, the return value of `require` doesn't tell you whether requiring succeeded or not (if it fails, it will raise an exception). `false` just means it's already loaded. Your statement

> Even after I set 'fileutils' to false in irb

doesn't make sense. You're not setting anything at all, you're just calling `require` again and the second time it returns false.

What you've observed just means that pry (or one of its dependencies) either loads FileUtils directly or loads a bit of the standard library that loads FileUtils. It looks like pry requires 'tempfile', which itself requires 'tmpdir' which in turn requires 'fileutils'.

Comment: You learn something every day. All the code you post is dealing with requiring the standard library "fileutils" and not the "file_utils" the gem provides.

Comment: Ok -- I think I understand.  So to confirm, the fileutils mentioned in the rubydoc [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html) actually references the standard library?